# Dynamic Rule Engine with UI support

Tags: rule-engine

I wanted to know about a rule engine with dynamic rules. It's like I have multiple consumers whose products I need to sell at different rates based on rules set by those customers. I would like to allow the customers to set rules using a UI and store the rules in a database.

Comment: Have you find any rulenegine to support your requirements ?